# CSS Class naming convention .sa-list li a > div{..}

Tags: css

I am going through a CSS example, and it has code like this:

```
.sa-list li label > span,
.sa-list li h3 > span,
.sa-list li h4 > span,
.sa-list li a > div{
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:10px 20px;
}
```

Can someone explain what's the relationship between say li, a and div and which style goes where?

Comment: `a b` is [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) while `a > b` is [children selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors). `a` is a descendant of `li` and `div` is the direct child of that `a`. Consider that as `ancestor father > son` :)

Comment: @Hashem, explained to perfection.

Comment: for further information: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Comment: Come on.. Please down-vote the question. :) I had only 17 rep! I genuinely had searched SO and wasn't being lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules all style a `span` that is direct child of a `label`, `h3` and `h4` and a `div` that is a direct child of an `a` tag, all of which are a descendant of an `li` that is also a descendant of an elements with the class of `sa-list`.

For instance:

```
<ul class="sa-list">
  <li>
    <label>
      <span><!-- this span is styled --></span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="sa-list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h4>
          <span><!-- this span is also styled --></span>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="sa-list">
  <li>
    <a>
      <div><!-- this div is styled --></div>
      <div><!-- as is this div --></div>
      <section>
        <div><!-- this div is not, b/c it is not a direct child of the a --></div>
      </section>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```